# Securing Client Password on Client Machine

Tags: c#, wcf, security, password-protection

When using the [`ChannelFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132(v=vs.110).aspx) class or a Generated Proxy to access a WCF Service is it possible to secure the client password on the client machine?

**Note: I am not talking about securing the password while it is going over the wire. Rather I am asking if it is possible to secure the password on the client's machine so that someone could not use a tool to expose the password while the user was logged on via a client application.**

I believe this to be an impossible goal. No matter how I obtain and secure the password from the user - The password will be exposed when setting the `ClientCredentials` on the `ChannelFactory` or Proxy object.

For example when setting `ClientCredentials` on a `ChannelFactory` object:

```
var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = GetUserName();
// Password will be set on channel factory as a string
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = GetPassword();
```

As long as the `ChannelFactory` instance is in memory then the password is insecure if someone possesses the client machine. I understand that encryption can be broken and that placing any file into the right hands means that it can be compromised. However, I wanted to see if at a minimum I could make someone work for it - but this seems to be a hole that limits what a developer can do to protect a system in the event that a client machine is physically accessed.

Is this just a fact of life when using Username/Password authentication to access a service?

Comment: In my experience, if the client is physically compromised, all bets are off anyway.

Comment: Yeah I agree that it is far from an ideal situation. I see the root of the problem being that the client credentials must be passed in some way that the service knows how to interpret predictably - Knowledge of that shared secret must be somewhere in the client.

Comment: You might be able to use a custom authentication module combined with a service that takes the username and password and returns an API key (this service wouldn't be secured other than with SSL), then put the API key in the username and leave the password blank and validate against a list of authorized keys.  Ensure you erase the original credentials.  If the API key is encoded with some type of machine local identification data then at least you can limit the use of the API key for as long as it was valid.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a hash of the password on the client machine and then matched it to the hash on the WCF Service?  That way you could store and send just the hash.

I've also done it where I would store the hash, but when I went to use it I would combine it with DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("DDHH") (Day + Hour) and hash it again. If it failed to match on the WCF side I would recheck using the hour before and the hour after.  [see here for hashing.](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/)